# How to navigate with BLocBuilder() - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm building my Flutter application with Bloc pattern and have a problem bellow:

With the BlocBuilder(), I can't navigate correct from page A to page B after pressed my button, it will push to page B and loop forever.

With the BlocListener(), I can navigate in fist time press my button, can't do it again in other press.

How to do navigate correct?

My code:

```
class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  Movies movie;
  double scale;
  MovieBLoc _movieBLoc;
  MovieItem({@required this.movie, this.scale});
  BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _movieBLoc = MovieBLoc();
    this.context = context;
    return BlocProvider<MovieBLoc>(
      create: (context) => _movieBLoc,
      child: BlocBuilder<MovieBLoc, MovieState>(
        builder: (context, movieState) {
          if (movieState is MovieNavigation) _onGoingToDetail();
          return _itemPageView(scale, movie);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemPageView(double scale, Movies movie) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        return Align(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _movieBackground(constraint, scale, movie),
              _filter(constraint, scale),
              _movieInfo(constraint, scale, movie),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _movieInfo(BoxConstraints constraint, double scale, Movies movie) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: ((constraint.maxHeight / 100) * 65) / scale,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              /* ... code ... */
              Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      // CLick on my button and navigate to page B
                      onPressed: () {
                        _movieBLoc.add(MoviePressed(movie: movie));
                      },
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        child: Text(
                          AppString.bookButtonValue,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppTheme.onSurface, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _onGoingToDetail() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RounterNames.pageB,
          arguments: MovieDetailArgs(movie: movie));
    });
  }

  /* ... code ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bloc package has documentation with different receipts.

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutternavigation?id=recipes-navigation

You definitely need to use BlocListener. Also please be aware to use Equitable with your events and states.

Because next state could be same and could be ignored if current state is 'NavigateState' and you again send new instance of 'NavigationState'